# Vba sumifs with loop

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to do a macro that does a sumif based on several conditions where one of those conditions is set by the value of the first cell of each row.

at the moment i have the following code:

```
For i = 20 To lngLastRow
    ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(RegJan, EquipaBd, EquipaForm, AgenteBd, AgenteForm, MarcasBD, ws.Cells(i, 1).Value)
    Next
```

the error that i am getting is in this line (i supouse that it is refering to the last condition used (ws.Cells(i, 1).Value).
i run this macro where i declared all the variables and for each row i had the following code

```
ws.Cells(20, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(RegJan, 
EquipaBd, EquipaForm, AgenteBd, AgenteForm, MarcasBD, MarcasForm1)
```

i declared all this variables like this:

```
Set MarcasForm1 = Sheets("Zoom").Range("A20")
```

but my sheet has more than 200 rows with diferent names in the first cell of each row, and i was thinking that with a loop i woul resolve this, but i am stuck. can anyone help me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the time consumed of you all, the problem was simple, I was declaring wrong one variable since the last cell value needed to be declared as a string, and it was int.
Thanks anyways